# am trying to write a simple if statement but my IDLE only reads the first part of my code and not the if statement if statement

Tags: if-statement

am trying to write a simple if statement but my IDLE only reads the first part of my code and not the if statement

```
  age=int(input("Enter your age"))
if age>=18:
  print("Congratulations you are eligible to vote")
```

Comment: how exactly please

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, just fix the indentation.

```py
age=int(input("Enter your age"))
if age>=18:
  print("Congratulations you are eligible to vote")
```